# JWPlayer in Drupal has container ID starting with Numeric Character

Tags: files

Following up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499767/jw-player-new-version-throws-an-error-and-doesnt-play-on-the-site) on SO, I am looking to change the default DIV container name that JWplayer provides to JWPlayer Div. The problem is that it starts with a numeric and that creates loading problems.

Is there a way, I can customize this JWPlayer ID ?

This is how it looks btw,

```
jwplayer('141ef7fe77391234fc105767808cc0a5').setup({"file":"my_video.mp4",
      "width":"838","height":"383","controlbar":"none",
      "modes":[{"type":"html5"},{"type":"flash","src":"http://path/jwplayer/player.swf"}]});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're at it, here is a quick solution to it.

Since this is a fix for Drupal JWPlayer Module, do the following:-

- Go to `jw_player` module folder and open `theme` folder.
- Open `jw_player.tpl.php` and add the following line on top (probably where PHP declaration starts).

> ```
> $html_id = "myvideo". $html_id;
> ```

It kinda does the job but I am sure you guys have better solutions than this. Please feel free to comment.

### Found a better solution

Don't do upper suggestion. Paste the following code in `jw_player.module` instead.

Find this line `$variables['html_id'] = md5(rand());` (I guess line 308) and uncomment it before pasting the following code instead.

```
while(1) {

      $variables['html_id'] = md5(rand());
      if (ctype_alpha(substr($variables['html_id'], 0, 1))) {
        //echo "First Digit is Alphabet";
        break;
      }

  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a good idea for an update to the jw player module, please submit an issue in its drupal.org issue queue so it can be added to the module. Everyone benefits and you don't have to run a hacked versino of the module.

Comment: Actually it seems it has already been fixed, it's just that it is in the 7.x-1.x dev branch not the last stable 1.x release. (I haven't checked 2.x yet). See https://www.drupal.org/node/1860056